# KeyValue class gives error in javafx? how i fix it

Tags: javafx

**KeyValue class gives error in javafx? I also implements all the abstract method but still face issue?**

```
    package at_collection;

    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.fxml.FXML;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
    import javafx.util.Duration;
    import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyValue;


    public class Scene1Controller implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private StackPane parent;
        @FXML
        private AnchorPane child1;
        @FXML
        private Button btn1;


        @Override
        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            // TODO
        }

        @FXML
        private void load1(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene2.fxml"));
            Scene scene = btn1.getScene();
            root.translateYProperty().set(scene.getHeight());

            parent.getChildren().add(root);

            Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
            KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(root.translateYProperty(), 0, Interpolator.EASE_IN); // Here is the problem
            KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), kv);
            timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);

            timeline.setOnFinished(t -> {
                parent.getChildren().remove(child1);
            });
            timeline.play();

        }

    }
```

The stack trace is not print. Because of the compile-time error. i'm actually implements this "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqskg3DYH8g"
[Here is the output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEaav.png)

Comment: [mcve] please .. including the complete stacktrace (as already noted by @Abra)

Comment: @Abra 

it's understandable now?

Comment: Copy the error message .. and don't re-add the specific 11 version tag, most probably it's the same for all recent versions

Comment: all that said: now that you added the imports, it looks like simply a wrong import - the KeyValue must be the fx type, not the crypto type :)

Comment: @kleopatra That's a right answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Wrong Import  "import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyValue"

Import this one "import javafx.animation.KeyValue;"